# Earth engine error: Number (Error) Image.subtract, argument 'image1': Invalid type. Expected type: Image<unknown bands>. Actual type: ImageCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image

I have some problem with my script, I'm trying to calculate MNDISI, and I've got some issues with errors:

> Number (Error)
> Image.subtract, argument 'image1': Invalid type.
> Expected type: Image.
> Actual type: ImageCollection.

```
var Jawa = ee.FeatureCollection("users/mohfaisal181099/KP/shp_jawa");
Map.centerObject(Jawa,7);
    
//Define Research Time
  var start = ee.Date('2020-01-01');
  var end = ee.Date('2020-12-31');

//Time Variable
var ndays = ee.Number(end.difference(start,'day')).round();
var nmonths = ee.Number(end.difference(start,'month')).round();
var nyears = ee.Number(end.difference(start,'year')).round();
print(ndays, 'ndays');
print(nmonths, 'nmonths');
print(nyears, 'nyears');

//Convert Kelvin to Celcius
  function celcius(img){
    return img.multiply(0.02).subtract(273.15)
              .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start']);
  }
//LST Terra MODIS 
  var terra_kelvin = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1')
                       .filterBounds(Jawa)
                       .select('LST_Day_1km')
                       .filterDate(start,end);
  var terra_LST = terra_kelvin.map(celcius);
  print(terra_LST);

  var modisProjection = terra_LST.first().projection();
  print('MODIS Projection:', modisProjection.nominalScale());
  
//Downsetting Function
function reduceres(image){
  return image.reduceResolution({
    reducer : ee.Reducer.mean(),
    maxPixels : 1024
  })
  .reproject({
    crs : modisProjection
  });
}

//Define Dataset
  //Terra MODIS Surface Reflectance
    var terra_SR = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD09GA')
                     .filterBounds(Jawa)
                     .filterDate(start,end)
                     .map(reduceres);

//Function Indices Terra MODIS
  var indices_terra_1 = function(a){
  //MNDWI
    var mndwi = a.expression(
                  '(Green - SWIR)/(Green + SWIR)',
                   {'Green': a.select('sur_refl_b04'),
                    'SWIR': a.select('sur_refl_b02')
                   }).rename('MNDWI');
    return a.addBands(mndwi)
            .copyProperties(a,['system:time_start']);
    };
  var terra_mndwi = terra_SR.map(indices_terra_1);
  var tst = terra_mndwi.first().projection();
  print('MNDWI Projection:', tst.nominalScale());
  //MNDISI
  var indices_terra_2 = function(aa){
    var mndisi = aa.expression(
                  '(LST - ((MNDWI + NIR + SWIR)/3))/(LST + ((MNDWI + NIR + SWIR)/3))',
                   {'LST': terra_LST.select('LST_Day_1km'),
                    'MNDWI': terra_mndwi,
                    'NIR' : aa.select('sur_refl_b02'),
                    'SWIR': aa.select('sur_refl_b06')
                   }).rename('MNDISI');
    return aa.addBands(mndisi)
             .copyProperties(aa,['system:time_start']);
    };
  var terra_mndisi = terra_SR.map(indices_terra_2);
  var tst2 = terra_mndisi.first().projection();
  print('MNDISI Projection:', tst2.nominalScale());
```

I have checked my script in detail and found that I made a mistake in the MNDISI calculation part, but I haven't found any related reference to help solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error appears because you are mixing in **indices_terra_2** function, images with ImageCollections in **mndisi** calculation. Following [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4fd369faa71d944c23acc40543f7af90) fixes such error by using list of images, instead ImageCollection, for retrieving adequate index in LST images.

```
var Jawa = ee.FeatureCollection("users/mohfaisal181099/KP/shp_jawa");
Map.centerObject(Jawa,7);

Map.addLayer(Jawa);

//Define Research Time
  var start = ee.Date('2020-01-01');
  var end = ee.Date('2020-12-31');

//Time Variable
var ndays = ee.Number(end.difference(start,'day')).round();
var nmonths = ee.Number(end.difference(start,'month')).round();
var nyears = ee.Number(end.difference(start,'year')).round();
print('ndays', ndays);
print('nmonths', nmonths);
print('nyears', nyears);

//Convert Kelvin to Celcius
function celcius(img){
    return img.multiply(0.02).subtract(273.15)
              .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start']);
}
  
//LST Terra MODIS 
var terra_kelvin = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1')
                       .filterBounds(Jawa)
                       .select('LST_Day_1km')
                       .filterDate(start,end);

var terra_LST = terra_kelvin.map(celcius);
print("terra_LST", terra_LST);

var terra_LST_lst = terra_LST.toList(terra_LST.size());

var modisProjection = terra_LST.first().projection();
print('MODIS Projection:', modisProjection.nominalScale());


//Downsetting Function
function reduceres(image){
  return image.reduceResolution({
    reducer : ee.Reducer.mean(),
    maxPixels : 1024
  })
  .reproject({
    crs : modisProjection
  });
}

//Define Dataset
//Terra MODIS Surface Reflectance
var terra_SR = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD09GA')
                     .filterBounds(Jawa)
                     .filterDate(start,end)
                     .map(reduceres);

print("terra_SR", terra_SR);

//Function Indices Terra MODIS
var indices_terra_1 = function(a){
  //MNDWI
  var mndwi = a.expression(
                  '(Green - SWIR)/(Green + SWIR)',
                   {'Green': a.select('sur_refl_b04'),
                    'SWIR': a.select('sur_refl_b02')
                   }).rename('MNDWI');
    return a.addBands(mndwi)
            .copyProperties(a,['system:time_start']);
    };
  
var terra_mndwi = terra_SR.map(indices_terra_1);
var tst = terra_mndwi.first().projection();

print("terra_mndwi", terra_mndwi);

print('MNDWI Projection:', tst.nominalScale());

//MNDISI
var terra_mndwi_lst = terra_mndwi.toList(terra_mndwi.size());

function indices_terra_2(aa){
  
  var idx = terra_mndwi_lst.indexOf(aa);
  
  var mndisi = ee.Image(aa).expression(
                  '(LST - ((MNDWI + NIR + SWIR)/3))/(LST + ((MNDWI + NIR + SWIR)/3))',
                   {'LST': ee.Image(ee.List(terra_LST_lst).get(idx)).select('LST_Day_1km'),
                    'MNDWI': ee.Image(aa).select('MNDWI'),
                    'NIR' : ee.Image(aa).select('sur_refl_b02'),
                    'SWIR': ee.Image(aa).select('sur_refl_b06')
                   }).rename('MNDISI');
    
    return ee.Image(aa).addBands(mndisi)
             .copyProperties(aa,['system:time_start']);

    }
    
var terra_mndisi = terra_mndwi_lst.map(indices_terra_2);

print("terra_mndisi", terra_mndisi);

var tst2 = ee.Image(terra_mndisi.get(0)).projection();
print('MNDISI Projection:', tst2.nominalScale());
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, it can be observed in following image that **MNDWI** and **MNDISI** bands were added to Image Collection list and **nominalScale** of first image was printed as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I've tried but got stuck when trying to visualize, in command said "Cannot add an object of type <List> to the map"

Answer (score 2):

There're two mistakes in your expression, you're defining a variable that is an `ImageCollection`, not an `image`; for 'LST' and 'MNDWI'.

The first fix is an easy one: you're mapping your second function to the original IC and not the output from the first function where you calculate 'MNDWI'. So you simply change `terra_SR.map(indices_terra_2)` to `terra_mndwi.map(indices_terra_2)`.

The second is a bit trickier as you need to add each image of `terra_LST` to `terra_SR`. You can use the 'system:index' property for this; these are unique for each day/image.

This code should work:

```
var Jawa = ee.FeatureCollection("users/mohfaisal181099/KP/shp_jawa");
Map.centerObject(Jawa,7);
    
//Define Research Time
  var start = ee.Date('2020-01-01');
  var end = ee.Date('2020-12-31');

//Time Variable
var ndays = ee.Number(end.difference(start,'day')).round();
var nmonths = ee.Number(end.difference(start,'month')).round();
var nyears = ee.Number(end.difference(start,'year')).round();
print(ndays, 'ndays');
print(nmonths, 'nmonths');
print(nyears, 'nyears');

//Convert Kelvin to Celcius
  function celcius(img){
    return img.multiply(0.02).subtract(273.15)
              .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start']);
  }
//LST Terra MODIS 
  var terra_kelvin = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1')
                       .filterBounds(Jawa)
                       .select('LST_Day_1km')
                       .filterDate(start,end);
  var terra_LST = terra_kelvin.map(celcius);
  print(terra_LST);

  var modisProjection = terra_LST.first().projection();
  print('MODIS Projection:', modisProjection.nominalScale());
  
//Downsetting Function
function reduceres(image){
  return image.reduceResolution({
    reducer : ee.Reducer.mean(),
    maxPixels : 1024
  })
  .reproject({
    crs : modisProjection
  });
}

//Define Dataset
  //Terra MODIS Surface Reflectance
    var terra_SR = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD09GA')
                     .filterBounds(Jawa)
                     .filterDate(start,end)
                     .map(reduceres)
                     .map(function(img){
                        return img.addBands(terra_LST.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index',img.get('system:index'))).first())
                     })
                     
//Function Indices Terra MODIS
  var indices_terra_1 = function(a){
  //MNDWI
    var mndwi = a.expression(
                  '(Green - SWIR)/(Green + SWIR)',
                   {'Green': a.select('sur_refl_b04'),
                    'SWIR': a.select('sur_refl_b02')
                   }).rename('MNDWI');
    return a.addBands(mndwi)
            .copyProperties(a,['system:time_start']);
    };
  var terra_mndwi = terra_SR.map(indices_terra_1);
  var tst = terra_mndwi.first().projection();
  print('MNDWI Projection:', tst.nominalScale());
  //MNDISI
  var indices_terra_2 = function(aa){
    var mndisi = aa.expression(
                  '(LST - ((MNDWI + NIR + SWIR)/3))/(LST + ((MNDWI + NIR + SWIR)/3))',
                   {'LST': aa.select('LST_Day_1km'),
                    'MNDWI': aa.select('MNDWI'),
                    'NIR' : aa.select('sur_refl_b02'),
                    'SWIR': aa.select('sur_refl_b06')
                   }).rename('MNDISI');
    return aa.addBands(mndisi)
             .copyProperties(aa,['system:time_start']);
    };
  var terra_mndisi = terra_mndwi.map(indices_terra_2);
  var tst2 = terra_mndisi.first().projection();
  print('MNDISI Projection:', tst2.nominalScale());
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried but got stuck when trying to visualize, in command said "Layer error: Image.visualize: Cannot provide a palette when visualizing more than one band"

Comment: Before adding a layer to the `Map`, try selecting the band you want to visualise with `.select('bandName')`